# Rational Numbers Proof

Tags: rational-numbers

Apologies for the vagueness before, I'm new here. I hope this clears it up:

Show that, for all non zero $b\in \Bbb Z$, $${(0,b)}=((a',b')\in F:a'=0)$$ $$F=((a,b)\in \Bbb Z*\Bbb Z: b\ne 0))$$ where F defines $\Bbb Q$

The problem states that it is a special class and to show that $(0,b)$ is the identity for sum. Because of that, define $0\in \Bbb Q$ as $(0,b)$

I'm confused on how to solve it. I know that $(a,b) \sim (a',b') <=> ab'-ba'=0$ and that addition in $\Bbb Q$ is defined as $(a,b)+(a',b')=(ab'+a'b,bb')$

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. As written, your question makes no sense. What are the pairs in parentheses? What are the primed variables? What is $F$? Please [edit] the question to include all the necessary words (not just symbols) and show us what you tried and where you are stuck. Then perhaps we can help.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense without context...and without definitions at all.

Answer (score 0):

Without some context, it's hard to tell what theorems you're allowed to use here.  But maybe you can multiply  both sides of your equation by $b'$ to get $(0,b) = (a,1)$?  Now the right side is an integer.

Comment: I'd say it's hard to even know what is this about at all. To begin with, what is $\;F\;$ , anyway?! And those ordered pairs seem to belong to a cartesian product with some further constraints...

Answer (score 0):

I assume you should have been taught that $(a,b) = (c,d)$ if and only if $a\times d = b\times c$.  Further, you should have been taught that the second entry may never be zero.

As such, you will have $(0,b)=(a',b')$ if and only if $0\times b' = b\times a'$.  In other words, you have $0=b\times a'$, but remembering that $b\neq 0$ that implies that $a'$ must be zero since $a$ and $b$ are elements of the integers which are well known to be an [integral domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_domain).

Similarly, $(b,b)=(a',b')$ if and only if $b\times b' = b\times a'$.  By subtracting to one side and factoring, we have $0 = b\times (b'-a')$.  By again noting the fact that $b$ is not allowed to be zero and the fact that the integers are an integral domain we get that it must be true that $(b'-a')$ must be zero.  So we have $b'-a'=0$ which by adding implies that $b'=a'$